# Why am I getting this error Makefile: No rule to make target 'timer.c', needed by 'timer.o'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

My working directory looks like this:

- main.c
- Makefile
- my_memmove.h
- my_memmove.c
- c-timer-lib

  - timer.c
  - timer.h

My makefile looks like this:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=gnu99 -g -Wall -Wextra -Ic-timer-lib
TARGET := output

output: main.o my_memmove.o timer.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.o my_memmove.o timer.o -o $(TARGET)

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c

my_memmove.o: my_memmove.c my_memmove.h
        gcc -c my_memmove.c

timer.o: c-timer-lib/timer.c c-timer-lib/timer.h
        gcc -c c-timer-lib/timer.c -o $@

clean:
        rm *.o $(TARGET)
```

I don't understand why I keep getting the "Makefile: No rule to make target 'timer.c', needed by 'timer.o'.  Stop." error. I believe that it's because the timer.c and timer.h files can't be found.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to incorporate the fixes posted in the answer, it just makes it confusing for others reading the question.  The question is now bad as it claims the posted makefile would give the error `Makefile: No rule to make target 'timer.c',` which in fact it would not

Comment: It would be a good idea to roll back the question to before any edits

Comment: and if you have a new question after reading the answer, post a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much confusion here! :)

First, this is definitely wrong:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I main.o ...
```

The `-I main.o` tells the compiler that it should use `main.o` as the name of a directory to search for include files.  That clearly won't work.  You should remove the `-I` here.

On to your problem: you have to realize that there are two completely different programs at play here: `make` which figures out how to run commands, and the commands that are being run, in this case the compiler `gcc`.

The `-I` option is an option to the *compiler* so that the compiler knows where to look for header files that are included by your source code with `#include`.

That option means nothing to make; it doesn't understand that option.  It's just some text to pass to the compiler.  Make is looking for the source file `timer.c` and it can't find it because you haven't told make where it is.

You have to write your rule to look in the correct place, like this:

```
timer.o: c-timer-lib/timer.c c-timer-lib/timer.h
            gcc -c c-timer-lib/timer.c -o $@
```

(you should always use `-o $@` so that your compile line puts the output file where make expects to find it, which will be put into the `$@` variable by make before it evaluates your recipe.)

**ETA**

Also, are you sure that `-DUNITS="ms"` is right?  We can't tell without seeing how `UNITS` is used in the source, but I suspect you probably need an extra level of quotes here, like `-DUNITS='"ms"'`

Really, you are trying to do too much in this makefile.  Make already knows how to correctly build object files from source files.  If you don't force the issue by writing your own rules, then make's built-in rules will do the job for you.  Your makefile can be written like this:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=gnu99 -g -Wall -Wextra -Ic-timer-lib -DUNITS='"ms"'
TARGET := output

$(TARGET): main.o my_memmove.o c-timer-lib/timer.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

my_memmove.o: my_memmove.h
c-timer-lib/timer.o: c-timer-lib/timer.h

clean:
        rm *.o $(TARGET)
```

make doesn't know which headers your source requires so you have to add the prerequisites by hand, although you can add extra rules to allow it to figure that out for itself.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry it's my first time making a Makefile.  I did -I because I wanted main to find the my_memmove.h header file. Do I need to specify where the compiler should find this? Or is it okay if I don't since it's in the same directory anyways.

Comment: It depends on how you did the `#include`.  If you use `#include "my_memmove.h"` then it will look in the current directory automatically.  If you use `#include <my_memmove.h>` then it won't.  If you want to add the current directory to the search path explicitly you have to use `-I.` (the `.` means "current directory", of course, like it always does).  The `-I` option _has_ to have an argument, it can't be left out.

Comment: Also, adding `-I` to the link line, as you did there, isn't useful.  The `-I` option tells the compiler where to search for `#include`d files, and `#include` directives are handled during the compile phase (turning the `.c` file into a `.o` file).  By the time you get to linking (turning `.o` files into an executable) there're no `#include` directives left and `-I` is useless.  If you want to use the `-I.` option it needs to be added to the `CFLAGS` variable, along with `-Ic-timer-lib`.